# Strange results when using \setkomavar{title} with scrlayer-scrpage and scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2, scrlayer-scrpage

Months ago, this code was working a letter:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,fromrule=afteraddress,fromphone,fromemail,title=true,subject=titled,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

    \setkomavar{fromname}{PN NN}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Meine \\Adresse\\hier}
    \setkomavar{fromphone}{ich \,bin \,er\,reich\,bar}
    \setkomavar{fromemail}{auch@mail.xx}
    \setkomavar{title}{Ein Titel taucht gar nicht auf}
    \setkomavar{subject}[Betreff:\,]{Betreff funktioniert}
    
    \begin{letter}{Meinem\\
        lieben Freund\\
        ebendort\\
        in wohnhaft}


        \nopagebreak

        \opening{Sehr geehrter lieber Freund!}
        Ein kurzer Text \ldots 

        \closing{Mit liebem Gruße,}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

When I insert an '*', like `\setkomavar{title}*{anytitle}` I can read the text "anytitle" in normal font size at the left top of my letter.

What would be the correct way to set a title with `scrlttr2` and `scrlayer-scrpage` to get the title before the `\opening{Dear ... ,}` ?

BTW: `\setkomavar{subject}{anytext}` works seemingly correct.
All other documented variables for `\setkomavar{variable}{anytext}` with the exception of 'title' work.

Comment: Workaround: `\documentclass{scrartcl}` + `\usepackage{scrletter}` + `\title{Titel}` + `\maketitle` combines the best of two worlds. You can use (nearly) all commands from `scrartcl` and from `scrlttr2`, even table of contents. See the documentation.

Comment: `\setkomavar{title}*{anytitle}` is the same as if you just write `anytitle` in your preamble. It breaks the `\setkomavar{some}{thing}, because this strangely starred version does not exist.

Comment: @Alexander Wittmann: If I follow your recommendation I get a real titlepage in the manner of scrartcl etc with date on the first page and on a second page my letter starts in a correct manner. What I intend to do is the a line after my letters head just before the \opening, like a subject line, just in \Large and centered, similar as a headline to say what type of letter it is (bill, reminder, etc). TIA, Georg

Comment: This is a bug in KOMA-Script version 3.36 (see https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/31/). It will be fixed in KOMA-Script version 3.37. Then `\setkomavar{title}{Title}` works again.

Answer (score 0):

I was instructed to solve the issue thanks to @esdd now in the following way: I put `subject=centered` as a KOMAoption in the \documentclass[options]{scrlttr2} and set  `\addtokomafont{subject}{\large} \\  \setkomavar{subject}{Title}` - that solved it.

The code complete:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,fromrule=afteraddress,fromphone,fromemail,subject=centered,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{graphics}



\begin{document}

    \setkomavar{fromname}{PN NN}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Meine \\Adresse\\hier}
    \setkomavar{fromphone}{ich \,bin \,er\,reich\,bar}
    \setkomavar{fromemail}{auch@mail.xx}
    \addtokomavar{subject}{\large}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Title}
%   \KOMAoptions{title}{title=afteropening}
%   \setkomavar{subject}[Betreff:\,]{Betreff funktioniert}
    
    \begin{letter}{Meinem\\
        lieben Freund\\
        ebendort\\
        in wohnhaft}


        \nopagebreak

        \opening{Sehr geehrter lieber Freund!}
        Ein kurzer Text \ldots 

        \closing{Mit liebem Gruße,}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `title` is an unknown value for option `subject`. Therefore you get a warning. Neither `\centering` nor `\large` takes an argument. They are switches. You could use opiton `subject=centered` and `\addtokomafont{subject}{\large}` and `\setkomavar{subject}{Title}`.